# Why <Route component={Menu}/> instead of <Menu />?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a submenu with Routes in my /About.
This submenu is called AboutMenu and is present at all pages under /About like => /About/Company and /About/Info.

An exercise example shows  `<Route component={AboutMenu} />` with `activeStyle={match.isExact && selectedStyle}>` and i just used `<AboutMenu />` and added `exact` to my AboutMenu Links instead.

Why would you use `<Route component={AboutMenu} />` instead of just rendering `<AboutMenu />`?

```
export const AboutMenu = (props) => {

    return (
        <div>
            <li>
                <NavLink exact to='/About' activeStyle={ activeStyle}> Company </NavLink>
            </li>
            <li>
                <NavLink to='/About/History' activeStyle={activeStyle}> History </NavLink>
            </li>
            <li>
                <NavLink to='/About/Vision' activeStyle={activeStyle}> Vision </NavLink>
            </li>
        </div>
    )
}
```

about section

```
const About = (props) => {

    return(
        <Template>
            <AboutMenu />
            {/* OR <Route component={AboutMenu} /> ?*/}
            <Route exact path='/About' component={Company} />
            <Route path='/About/History' component={History} />
            <Route path='/About/Vision' component={Vision} />
        </Template>
    )
}

export default About
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<Route>` with no `path` will always match. So, both

```
<AboutMenu />
```

and

```
<Route component={AboutMenu} />
```

will result in the `AboutMenu` component always rendered. That is, in this particular case you can use either of them interchangeably.

However, there *is* a difference between the two in cases where the `<Switch>` component is used. Look at this example:

```
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/" exact component={Home}/>
    <Route path="/will-match" component={WillMatch}/>
    <Route component={NoMatch}/>
  </Switch>
```

Here,

```
<Route component={NoMatch}/>
```

comes last, and it will *only* match if no routes matched before it, acting like the `default case` of the traditional `switch` statement in many programming languages. It will not match if one of the two routes above it matches, and subsequently the `NoMatch` component will not be rendered. If instead the last route there was just

```
<NoMatch />
```

the `NoMatch` component would *always* be rendered.